# How to go back to previous fragment with the same tab selected?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I implemented a swipe tab in a fragment. This fragment has two tabs, tab1 and tab2. when i click on tab2, a new activity will load. however, when i click on the back button, it directs to the fragment but not the tab i selected previously. it should display tab2 not tab1 contents. how can i do that?

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345827/fragment-rotation/32346072#32346072)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember on which tab you were `onStop()`, for example using `SharedPreferences`, or `startActivityWithResult` when you start your activity. Then when you come back, check `onStart()` and retrieve from the `SharedPreferenes`, or 'onResult' and move the tab to the good tab.