# Save state of dynamic ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, savestate

I have an android app in which I want to dynamically add and remove Fragments to a ViewPager during runtime, and preserving the Fragments on configuration changes.

Thus far I have implemented a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, holding my Fragments in a list with methods `add`, `remove` and `replace` to manipulate my Fragments. Basically, all they do is insert or delete a Fragment in the list and then call `notifyDatasetChanged()`. I insert the staring Fragment as a new Fragment during the Activitys `onCreate()` method.

I know want to preserve my Fragments during configuration changes. Currently, when I change my screen orientation, all my currently Fragments are deleted, and I get back to the starting Fragment, naturally because the Activity is recreated, and the Fragment and the Adapater are reinstantiated during the `onCreate()` call. I was trying to save the state of the Adapter with the `Adapter.saveInstance()` during the Activitys `onPause()`, but when I try to restore it via `Adapter.restoreInstance()`, I get an empty adapter.

Can anyone give me a hint on what is the correct way in Android to save state a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the state of the **current** fragment, i think first of all you will have to check which fragment is currently added/visible in the container activity. Once you have that fragment, simply use **onSaveInstanceState()** method of the container activity to save the instance of the current fragment.

For code snippet please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345827/fragment-rotation/32346072#32346072) link.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. I had to put it in a for() loop to save all Fragments in my Adapter, but it seems to be working like expected

Comment: Well this actually works only for a limited amount of fragments. When I want to save fragments that are away more than 1 screen of my current fragment, I get an "Fragment not in FragmentManager" error. Any hints on that?

Comment: In onSaveInstanceState() you will save only that fragment which is currently attached/visible to the user. So, the next time when the user re-creates the activity on screen rotation, he will go back to the same fragment that was last visible. Thus, at a time you will one only one fragment visible in your container activity

Comment: But I need to recreate *all* fragments in my ViewPager

Comment: One solution that i can think of is that you save the position of your current view pager fragment in onSaveInstanceState() and once the activity gets re-created you populate your view pager like the way you do and then set it to the position that you had saved in the onSaveInstanceState().

Comment: You see, that's the problem, I populate my view pager dynamically, so I don't know during onCreate() which Fragments with which arguments I have in my view pager, so I need a way to store that information